# 2D array - specify amount to new 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2-d array of double numbers it's 48 by 48, I am trying to make a method that will allow the user to select a specific amount e.g. = 7 by 7 and then put that into a new 2d array.

```
public static double[][] amountOTP(double [][] a, int x){
    a = new double[x][x];
    return a;
}
```

thats all i have right now, this takes an 2d array as input however even though i specified x it doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly should the new array contain?

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* - what does that mean? What do you expect to happen, what happens instead?

Comment: Do you mean that you wish to cut off the size of the 2d array to that of the number specified by the user? (So basically make the 2d array smaller, but have it keep its values?)

Comment: @AlexanderDaum my 2d array matrix is 48 by 48, basically i want this method to make a new 2d array that contains only 7 by 7 of that data from the original 2d array

Comment: @YorickIsTheBest yes sir

Comment: you need to use a loop to copy in the old values to the new array

Comment: @domdom i want to cut off the array to what the user requests so a 48 by 48 matrix, can be cut down to 7 by 7

Comment: Then you also need to copy the data from the array passed as argument to the array the method creates. Not just create a new array and return it.

Comment: @JokesOnyou Ok. A few of us have posted our answers below. Pick whichever one works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you already have a lot of answers, but nobody was making use of the excellent Arrays.copyOf Java API method:

```
public static double[][] amountOTP(double [][] a, int x){
    a = Arrays.copyOf(a, x);
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i] != null) {
            a[i] = Arrays.copyOf(a[i], x);
        } else {
            a[i] = new double[x]; // allows growth
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if I'm wrong, but I'm assuming for now that you want your method to return a smaller 2d array which contains some of the values of the given array, in which case you would need to change your method to this:

```
public static double[][] amountOTP(double [][] a, int x) {
   double[][] b = new double[x][x];
   x = Math.min(x, a.length);
   for(int i = 0;i < x; i++)
      for(int j = 0;j < x; j++)
         b[i][j] = a[i][j];
   return b;
}
```

This should work fine but feel free to comment and inform me if I left anything out or it doesn't work; I'm here to help. Anyways, I hope this works for you. (Also, if this isn't the answer you were looking for, feel free to tell me.)

Note: This should avoid `IndexOutOfBounds` exceptions, so it will still work correctly if the user gives an `x` value bigger than the size of `a`. The 2d array that this method returns will just have some values of zero where it couldn't find any numbers.

Comment: @JokesOnyou No problem! Glad I could help.

Comment: @OsumaneMahyDiaw If the length is less than the original array, then yes. The values will be copied. (Not all of them however; just the ones that can fit.) And I had assumed that the 1d arrays inside `a` were all the same size *and* equal to the length of `a` itself, making the 2d array a square. If the OP requires it, I will edit my answer to accommodate for a matrix which is not a square.

Comment: `x<a.length?x:a.length` use Math.min or at least add some spaces.

Comment: @PatrickParker forgot about spaces so I'll add that now, but `Math.min`? `x` is an integer...

Comment: @YorickIsTheBest yes it works with ints too. some might prefer it over ternary operator for clarity, especially when answering beginners

Comment: @PatrickParker Oh. I was thinking of `Math.floor`... Anyways, I guess I could use it.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to cut it ro a smaller size and copy the part of the original array, this should work:

```
public static double [][] cutArray (double [][] a, int newSize){
  if (x > a.length)
     throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Can only make array smaller");
  double [][] b = new double [newSize][newSize];
  for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < newSize; j++){
      b [i][j] = a [i][j];
    }
  }
  return b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution below considers situations in which the requested new two-dimensional array length is greater than the original in which case we simply return the original.

Example:

```
public static double[][] amountOTP(double [][] a, int x){
       if(x > a.length) return a;
       for (double[] arr : a)
          if(arr.length < x)
             return a;

       double[][] newArray = new double[x][x];
       for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
          for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
             newArray[i][j] = a[i][j];

       return newArray;
}
```

Comment: description does not match code: "requested length ... is less than original" should read "is greater"

Answer (score 1):

I think it's something like that you're looking for :

```
public static double[][] amountOTP(double [][] a, int x){
    double [][] ret = new double[x][x];

    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < x; j++)
            ret[i][j] = a[i][j];
    return ret;
}
```

But you have to be careful with the parameters because it can cause an IndexOutOfBounds exception

Answer (score 0):

you are actually not yet initializing the array so the method should be like this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double[][] a=amountOTP(3);
        for(int j=0;j<a.length;++j)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<a[j].length;++i)
            {
                a[j][i]=2;
            }
        }
        for(int j=0;j<a.length;++j)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<a[j].length;++i)
            {
                System.out.println(a[j][i]);
            }
        }


    }
    public static double[][] amountOTP(int x)
    {
        return new double[x][x];

    }
```

Comment: @JokesOnyou if this help, you can accept it as an answer